# Onchange Doesn't Fire

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner

I am told that onchange fires when the value changes.  I have a text box with an onchange attached to it.  Then set the focus to the text box.  When I scan a barcode thereby changing the textbox value onchange does not fire?  I need to call a function when the scanner activates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**onchange** is primarily used to Select box

Use **onKeyPress** or **onKeyUp** for text box.

Edit: with Barcode scanner you might have to trigger an onFocus or onblur

Comment: I use focus already to direct the scanners output to the textbox.

Comment: try the jQuery on input $(element).on('input',function(){

Comment: You said it first regarding the on input event.  Much better than onchange for this barcode scenario

Answer (score 1):

Use the `input` event. It's like `change` but no dependency on another event like `blur`. I'd make an example, but you have no code to work upon. See [**ARTICLE**](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php)

If you want to use `change`, you can simply use:

```
   var txt = document.getElementById('txtbx');
   txt.blur();
```

or simular to that.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event doesn't fire until the textbox looses focus, which also causes a `blur` event.

There are a couple of ways of handling  this.  If your barcode software can sent out a `end-of-text` string, that's best.  Otherwise, you can use the `keyup` event to count the number of characters.